# django redirect not redirecting

Tags: django, redirect, django-forms, django-urls

I have the following form logic in my view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            my_form = form.save()                                          )
            print 'before redirect'
            redirect('customer:department-edit')
            print 'after redirect'
```

My url entry looks like this:

```
url(r'^departments/$', views.departments_view, name='department-edit'),
```

I get the following output:

```
before redirect
after redirect
```

Why would the redirect not occur after the form is submitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you forgot to add a **`return`** statement before `redirect()`.

Why is there a need for a `return` ? Because the `redirect` method is just a shortcut to a `HttpResponseRedirect`, so it behaves like any other action: it has to return a response.

So your code should look like this:

```
...
print 'before redirect'
return redirect('customer:department-edit')
print 'after redirect'
...
```

See The [Django Documentation example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) :)